# Apple Watch screen stays blank telerik

Tags: ios, cordova, telerik, apple-watch

I use Telerik-AppleWatch plugin for cordova.
i followed the instructions and i copied the simplified example from   the project.
when i run the project the Built successfully but on the iwatch  i see just the name of the app and blank screen.
I didn't receive error on the console.

i use xcode. target is- 8.2 
There is not much information on the internet about it

```
function initAppleWatch() {
applewatch.init(function () {
    alert("init");
    onAppRequestsUpdate();
    onGlanceRequestsUpdate();
});
applewatch.callback.onLoadAppMainRequest = onAppRequestsUpdate;
applewatch.callback.onLoadGlanceRequest = onGlanceRequestsUpdate;
```

}

can anybody know what can i do?

I work on it all week without success

thanks!:)